# docker --tls vs --tlsverify

Tags: ssl, docker

The docker cli tool provides two options for tls auth: `--tls` and `--tlsverify`.

**What's the difference between these two options?**

I've set up my remote docker daemon to use some TLS certs I've made using openssl. I'm able to connect to the daemon using the `--tls` flag but *not* using the `--tlsverify`

Comment: Long time but did you find any suitable convenient answer? I am trying for the same. I ain't able to get in google.

Answer (score 5):

If you "made" the certificates yourself (i.e., self-signed), it's unlikely that the certificates can be verified. Using the `--tls` option simply instructs Docker to use the certificates as-is without verifying the certificate with root authorities. `--tlsverify` requires that the certificate can be verified with a root authority before it is used.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/ for more details, specifically (emphasis mine):

> If you need Docker to be reachable via the network in a safe manner, you can enable TLS by specifying the tlsverify flag and pointing Docker’s tlscacert flag to a **trusted CA certificate**.
>
> In the daemon mode, it will only allow connections from clients authenticated by a **certificate signed by that CA**. In the client mode, it will only connect to servers with a **certificate signed by that CA**.

In other words, the behavior you're experiencing is less of a Docker problem and more of a certificate problem.

Comment: Aaron thank you! this makes sense. Does docker-machine use self-signed certs as well?

Comment: I don't know anything about docker-machine, unfortunately. However, it's probably a safe assumption that if you don't know whether or not you're generating a trusted certificate, you probably aren't.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is true, because there are [some](https://gist.github.com/cameron/10797040) [reports](https://gist.github.com/bradrydzewski/a6090115b3fecfc25280) of using `--tlsverify` with self-signed certs.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it myself, and `--tlsverify` happily works with self-generated CA, it just verifies the certs against the CA, it does NOT verify the CA against any trusted roots, or the certificate against any other trusted roots. So this answer is definitely wrong.